# Rerturing a file to the browser when a button is clicked in .Net Web Forms

Tags: .net, asp.net, webforms

I have a .Net web forms page, that has a data grid on it and some other things.  I need to add a button that when clicked it will generate a comma separated file.  I have already done this on the server side. It is sitting in memmory in a string variable.
What I need to do is return it to the browser in a way that the browser sees it as a file.  Whats the best way to do this?

I have been working in the MVC world for so long that I'm starting to forget things in the Forms world.

Comment: "I have been working in the MVC world for so long that I'm starting to forget things in the Forms world." @7wp, this is not a bad thing at all.....

Comment: @Doug The problem is some things are abstracted out so much that i don't know what is going on on the wire anymore you know? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is asp classic but, I think you'll get the gist of it. OnClick event with Server.Transfer to a page with code similar to the below.

```
Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = False 'True
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & PageTitle & ".xls"  
Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
     HERE GET YOUR FILE AND SEND IT TO THE RESPONSE AS A STRING.... 
     RESPONSE.FLUSH
```

Comment: Ya its almost identical just had to add Response.End() at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Response.TransmitFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx). Here's an example from [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET).

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=SailBig.jpg");
Response.TransmitFile( Server.MapPath("~/images/sailbig.jpg") );
Response.End();
```